Hibernate changes UpperCamelCase to lower_snake_case when parsing values in @Column and @Table annotations
this is how entity is defined:
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Recipes")
public class BoardRow {
    @Id
    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "UserName")
    private String senderName;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "UserEmail")
    private String senderEmailAddress;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "DocumentLink")
    private String documentUrl;
}

these are my hibernate configurations in the application.properties file:
# Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.database.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl

and yet, when I try to fetch entities through my repository, I receive this error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "recipes" does not exist
as you can see, hibernate de-capitalized my table name, resulting in a mismatch between the SQL it tries to run and my actual table definition.
I was under the impression that the
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
should take care of exactly that, but it appears to be completely ignored.
Furthermore, here's the query it tried to run -
JDBC exception executing SQL [select b1_0.id,b1_0.document_link,b1_0.user_email,b1_0.user_name from recipes b1_0 where b1_0.user_email=?]
as you can see, the SQL is in lower_snake_case, unlike the UpperCamelCase values that were provided by the @Column and @Table annotations

You have spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none set, meaning you must be creating your DB tables via Flyway or some other migration tool?

@EthanConrad good catch, I'm currently writing a micro-service that connects to an existing database for read-only purposes, that's why I'm not interfering with the DDL or DML of my DB.
